# best practice for logging mechanisam in ETL processing

Tags: azure, pyspark, etl, azure-databricks, azure-log-analytics

What is the  best practice for logging mechanisam in ETL processing?

Actually we are  developing ETL application .in this we want to use log analaytics to log data
Could anybody provide best practice for logging mechanism at industry standards.

i have googled below link :https://www.timmitchell.net/post/2016/03/14/etl-logging/

any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I recently implemented one in one of the organisation. It is a custom built because of the technology choice. Following is what is included in the logging.

- It acts as a wrapper around any ETL job aka there is a template developed and the template has in built logging
- The template has a feature of master and child job and logs based on master or child
- **The logging captures the following:**

- Status of the job - success, failure, warning
- Source details (e.g name of file or source table etc name)
- data classification tagging
- business owner of the incoming data source
- row count of raw file vs the row count loaded

- Send an alert to a distribution list if the job fails
- Raises a ticket via service desk if job fails

It depends on your requirements, you may want to capture more or less.
Good luck

Comment: HI 

Thanks to reply

Comment: HI 

Thanks to reply

Actually we are using data bricks and pyspark to implement  ETL and using Azure  log analytics  for logging mechanism 
Could you suggest me How to implement with these technologies

Comment: Hi @NarsingRao i have not used Azure log analytics yet. But i am assuming it has a storage engine under the hood which probably is a file storage system. All suggestions i put above were custom developed and unfortunately many of these you may have to log manually. Databircks  as an application will log easily to log analytics. You may have to echo (custom code) the other messages to the databricks console to capture through the log analytics.

Comment: Hi Amandeep Modgil 

Could we get any projects git hub or online for reference?

Thanks in advance